# asp.net mvc 3 rc1. ModelBinder populates all properties with null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, default, modelbinder

I have an object like this

```
public class ParentEntityInfo
{
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string ParentProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and view for this object is:

```
<%=Html.Hidden("parentInfo.ParentId", parentInfo.ParentId)%>
<%=Html.Hidden("parentInfo.ParentProperty", parentInfo.ParentProperty)%>
<%=Html.Hidden("parentInfo.EntityName", parentInfo.EntityName)%>
```

I have the case where parentInfo is null and I post this form to controller. On the controller action

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(..., ParentEntityInfo parentInfo)
```

I receive constructed object parentInfo but all properties are null. In this case I would rather prefer to have whole parentInfo to be null. I there any possibility to tell default model binder do not pass such object? Or probably I can modify something in this code to make it work this way. I think in mvc 2.0 it worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HiddenFor(...)` helper instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference. Eventually both helpers will render the same thing like <input type="hidden" name="parentInfo.parentId"/>. And model binder will take care of how to proccess the data. Your suggestion is cleaner but I can't convert my project right now from ViewData to ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default model binder will always use Activator.CreateInstance to bind complex action parameters. What you can do is use ModelState.IsValid to assess whether the parameter was bound successfully. I think in your case this will be false by default, but if not you could add the necessary attribute to ensure this behaviour e.g.

```
public class ParentEntityInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Parent required")]
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string ParentProperty { get; set; }
}
```